# How to install drush for a vagrant project?

Tags: vagrant, drush

I have drush installed in my system but drush does not work inside vagrant. It works for MAMP though.

Here is drush status 
 drush status
 Drupal version         :  7.41
 Site URI               :  http://default
 Default theme          :  garland
 Administration theme   :  garland
 PHP configuration      :  /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
 Drush version          :  5.10.0
 Drush configuration    :  /var/www/project_name/sites/all/drush/drushrc.php
 Drush alias files      :  /home/vagrant/.drush/project_name.aliases.drushrc.php 
 Drupal root            :  /var/www/npro/docroot
 Site path              :  sites/default
 File directory path    :  sites/default/files

Comment: Can somebody please provide me the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In settings.php file, mine is multi site. I added following code to sites/xyz_site/settings.php

```
Add following code
$databases = array(
  'default' =>
  array(
    'default' =>
    array(
      'database' => 'database_name',
      'username' => 'root',
      'password' => 'root',
      'host' => 'localhost',
      'port' => '',
      'driver' => 'mysql',
      'prefix' => '',
    ),
  ),
);

$conf['file_public_path'] = 'sites/xyz_site/files';
```

Above solution worked for me.